# How do you fresh an ItemListAdapter in a PageViewAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

Right off the bat...I'm new to Android so I apologize in advance.  I have an Activity(PlacementFragment) extends a FragmentActivity.  The PlacementActivity has a FragmentPagerAdapter.    The FragmentPagerAdapter uses the PlacementFragment that extends Fragment.  Within the PlacementFragment I have a ListViewAdapter.  In the PlacementActivity I would like a custom search box in the action bar that when done entering criteria, it would run a AsyncTask(SearchActivity) to query an external database.  Once the AsyncTask was complete I would like to refresh the (Activity, Fragment, PageViewAdapter, or ListViewAdapter) ??  Not sure how to do this.  I have tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() for both ListView and Pager.  I have tried to replace fragment, start new Intent, clear list and add new items.

When I debug I can see my listItems have the updated values from the AsyncTask but I can't get the list to update.

PlacementActivity

```
    package com.operatorschool.ats;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.lang.reflect.Method;

    /**
     * Created by MDK177 on 6/12/2014.
     */
    public class PlacementActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
        ViewPager mViewPager;
        private TextView tvMessage;

        public static String userData;
        public static String[] Courses = {"Heavy", "Crane", "Truck", "Drilling", "RigSig"};

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(com.operatorschool.ats.R.layout.activity_viewpager);

            Intent inPlacement = getIntent();
            userData = inPlacement.getStringExtra("data");
            tvMessage = findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the primary sections
            // of the app.
            mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


            // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
            // parent.
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // add the custom view to the action bar
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_layout);
            EditText search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(
                    R.id.searchBox);
            search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                              KeyEvent event) {
                    //Toast.makeText(PlacementActivity.this, "Search triggered",
                    //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    new SearchActivity(PlacementActivity.this, tvMessage, "placement",
                            "trn_Job_Postings", "zip", "=", v.getText().toString()).execute("trn_Job_Postings", "zip", "=", v.getText().toString());


                    //Intent intent = getIntent();
                    // Finish the activity
                    //finish();
                    // Restart the activity
                    //startActivity(intent);

                    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

                    return false;
                }
            });
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);


            // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
            // user swipes between sections.
            mViewPager = findViewById(com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener (new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
                    // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
                    // Tab.
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

            // Sliding Tab Layout Attempt
            //mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
            //mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

            // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
            for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
                // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
                // listener for when this tab is selected.
                actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()
                                .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                                .setTabListener(this));
            }

            forceTabs();
        }

        public void forceTabs() {
            try {
                final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                final Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass()
                        .getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
                setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
                setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, false);
            }
            catch(final Exception e) {
                // Handle issues as needed: log, warn user, fallback etc
                // This error is safe to ignore, standard tabs will appear.
            }
        }

        public String getUserData(){
            return userData;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }


        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
         * sections of the app.
         */
        public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = new PlacementFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                if(userData != null && !userData.isEmpty()) {
                    args.putInt(PlacementFragment.ARG_COURSE_NAME, i);
                    args.putString(PlacementFragment.ARG_COURSE_DATA, userData);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                }

                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
                if (object instanceof PlacementFragment) {
                    //return POSITION_UNCHANGED; // don't force a reload
                } else {
                    // POSITION_NONE means something like: this fragment is no longer valid
                    // triggering the ViewPager to re-build the instance of this fragment.
                    //return POSITION_NONE;
                }

                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return Courses.length;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return Courses[position];
            }

        }

        /**
         * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
         */

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_search:

                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miDownloads:
                    Intent inDownloads = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(inDownloads);
                    break;
                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miStartDates:
                    Intent inStartDates = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartDatesActivity.class);
                    inStartDates.putExtra("data", userData);
                    startActivity(inStartDates);
                    break;
                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miApplication:
                    Intent inApplication = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApplicationActivity.class);
                    inApplication.putExtra("data", userData);
                    startActivity(inApplication);
                    break;
                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miContacts:
                    Intent inCounselor = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactsActivity.class);
                    inCounselor.putExtra("data", userData);
                    startActivity(inCounselor);
                    break;
                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miHome:
                    Intent inHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    inHome.putExtra("data", userData);
                    startActivity(inHome);
                    break;
                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miTranscript:
                    Intent inTranscript = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TranscriptActivity.class);
                    inTranscript.putExtra("data", userData);
                    startActivity(inTranscript);
                    break;
                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miCredentials:
                    Intent inCredentials = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CredentialsListActivity.class);
                    inCredentials.putExtra("data", userData);
                    startActivity(inCredentials);
                    break;
                case com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.miPlacement:
                    Intent inPlacement = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlacementActivity.class);
                    inPlacement.putExtra("data", userData);
                    startActivity(inPlacement);
                    break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

PlacementFragment

```
package com.operatorschool.ats;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class PlacementFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public static String ARG_COURSE_NAME = "course_name";
    public static String ARG_COURSE_DATA = "course_data";
    public static String[] Courses = {"Heavy", "Crane", "Truck", "Drilling", "RigSig"};
    int image_id;

    ListView listView;
    List<PlacementRowItem> rowItems;
    PlacementListViewAdapter adapter;

    private JSONObject userData;
    private JSONObject postingData;
    private JSONObject coursePostingsData;
    private View rootView;
    private Bundle args;
    private Activity parentActivity;
    //private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(com.operatorschool.ats.R.layout.activity_viewpager_list, container, false);
        args = getArguments();

        //PlacementActivity pActivity = (PlacementActivity) getActivity();
        //String plData = sdActivity.getUserData();

        parentActivity = ((PlacementActivity)getActivity());
        //parentActivity.recreate();

        //listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        //listView.setAdapter(null);

        ///mViewPager = parentActivity.findViewById(com.operatorschool.ats.R.id.pager);
        //mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);


        try{

            userData = new JSONObject(args.getString(ARG_COURSE_DATA));
            postingData = userData.getJSONObject("Postings");

            if(postingData.has(Courses[args.getInt(ARG_COURSE_NAME)])) {
                coursePostingsData = postingData.getJSONObject(Courses[args.getInt(ARG_COURSE_NAME)]);

                getItems();

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.d("POSTINGS", e.toString());
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //if(rowItems != null){
        //    rowItems.clear();
        //    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //}


        //getItems();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    private void getItems(){

        rowItems = new ArrayList<PlacementRowItem>();
        rowItems.clear();


        for (Iterator<String> iterator = coursePostingsData.keys(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            String sd = iterator.next();
            try {

                JSONObject postingInfo = coursePostingsData.getJSONObject(sd);
                String company = postingInfo.getString("company");
                String position = postingInfo.getString("other");
                String location = "";
                String website = "";
                String email = "";
                String telephone = "";

                if(postingInfo.has("address")) {
                    if (postingInfo.getString("address") != "null") {
                        location = location + postingInfo.getString("address") + ", ";
                    }
                }

                location = location + postingInfo.getString("city") + " " + postingInfo.getString("state") + ", " + postingInfo.getString("zip");

                if(postingInfo.has("website")) {
                    website = postingInfo.getString("website");
                }

                if(postingInfo.has("email")) {
                    email = postingInfo.getString("email");
                }

                if(postingInfo.has("telephone")) {
                    telephone = postingInfo.getString("telephone");
                }


                if (Courses[args.getInt(ARG_COURSE_NAME)] == "Heavy") {
                    image_id = com.operatorschool.ats.R.drawable.ic_pl_pin_heavy;
                } else if (Courses[args.getInt(ARG_COURSE_NAME)] == "Crane") {
                    image_id = com.operatorschool.ats.R.drawable.ic_pl_pin_crane;
                } else if (Courses[args.getInt(ARG_COURSE_NAME)] == "Drilling") {
                    image_id = com.operatorschool.ats.R.drawable.ic_pl_pin_drilling;
                } else if (Courses[args.getInt(ARG_COURSE_NAME)] == "RigSig") {
                    image_id = com.operatorschool.ats.R.drawable.ic_pl_pin_rigsig;
                } else {
                    image_id = com.operatorschool.ats.R.drawable.ic_pl_pin_truck;
                }

                //String posting, String location, int image_id, String link, String email, String telephone

                PlacementRowItem item = new PlacementRowItem(company, position, location, image_id, website, email, telephone);
                rowItems.add(item);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.d("POSTINGS", e.toString());
            }
        }

        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);

        adapter = new PlacementListViewAdapter(getActivity(), com.operatorschool.ats.R.layout.placement_list_item, rowItems);

        //adapter.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        listView.invalidate();
        adapter.addAll(rowItems);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Activity p = getActivity();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

}
```

SearchActivity

```
package com.operatorschool.ats;

/**
 * Created by MDK177 on 5/14/2014.
 */

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import static com.operatorschool.ats.Utilities.toTitleCase;

public class SearchActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private JSONObject json;
    private TextView tvMessage;
    private String ActivitySelected;
    private String db_table, db_field, db_criteria, db_logical_operator;
    private FragmentActivity mainActivity;
    public static String[] Courses = {"Heavy", "Crane", "Truck", "Drilling", "RigSig"};

    public SearchActivity(Context context, TextView strMessage, String activity, String db_table,
                          String db_field, String db_logical_operator, String db_criteria){
        this.context = context;
        this.tvMessage = strMessage;
        this.ActivitySelected = toTitleCase(activity);
        this.db_table = db_table;
        this.db_field = db_field;
        this.db_criteria = db_criteria;
        this.db_logical_operator = db_logical_operator;

        mainActivity = (FragmentActivity) context;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Searching " + this.ActivitySelected + "... please wait!");

        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args){
        try{
            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("tbl", args[0]);
            postDataParams.put("fld", args[1]);
            postDataParams.put("log", args[2]);
            postDataParams.put("cri", args[3]);

            //Log.d("params",postDataParams.toString());


            try {
                URL url = new URL("{LEFT OUT ON PURPOSE}");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();
                }else {
                    return "";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            //Log.d("Exception:", e.getMessage());
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String key= itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String data){
        String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
        String TAG_DATA = "data";

        try {
            json = new JSONObject(data);
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            String message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            String user_info = json.getString(TAG_DATA);

            if(success == 1){
                if(this.ActivitySelected.equals("Placement")) {
                    // TODO change fragment
                    //Intent inApp = new Intent(this.context, ApplicationFragment.class);
                    //inApp.putExtra("data", user_info);
                    //inApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    //this.context.startActivity(inApp);

                    //Activity activity = (AppCompatActivity ) context;

                    /*FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

                    Fragment f = new PlacementFragment();

                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putInt( "course_name" , 0);
                    arguments.putString( "course_data" , user_info);
                    f.setArguments(arguments);

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setTransition(transaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

                    LinearLayout contentView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.llFragment);

                    transaction.replace(contentView.getId(), f);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
*/
                    //PlacementActivity.userData = user_info;

                }
            }else{
                this.tvMessage.setText(message);
                this.tvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }catch (Exception e){
            //Log.d("onPostExecuteError", e.toString());
            //this.tvMessage.setText("There was an error logging in. Please try again!");
            //this.tvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error with your request. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So a `ViewPager` pre-creates the views either side of the current view.

Unfortunately the `setOffscreenPageLimit` minimum value is 1 (the default).

This means the `onCreateView` of any fragments next to the current never gets called when you are on the page or page next to it, for it to then do something with the listview's updated data.

You are basically have nested adapters with the viewpager caching pages, so you need to tell the inner adapter it's content has changed and the outer adapter it's content has changed.

I work around this by notifying the ViewPager Adapter has changed `mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in your case.

Update: I notify the view pager adapter has a changed page using an `addOnPageChangeListener` on the viewpager, which gets called when you switch to the page with the content that needs updating, BUT you could do it as soon as the data on the other pages needs updating but this might cause a re-draw of the current page.

e.g.

```java
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                // Pages 1 and 2 have dynamic content, page 0 has static content
                if (position == 1 || position == 2)
                {
                    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // Code goes here
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Code goes here
            }
        });
```

This gets the view pager to re-create the required pages next to the current.

Note you could do some optimisations to make sure you only notify the view pager adapter to change when absolutely necessary, but in my case most of the time cached viewpager page needs updating.

I then override `getItemPosition` in the view pager adapter `AppSectionsPagerAdapter` in your case, as this gets called for every page and is passed the fragment as an object.

To call an update function e.g.

```java
@Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            if (object instanceof PlacementFragment) {
                PlacementFragment f = (PlacementFragment) object;
                if (f != null) {
                    f.update();
                    // Or in your case the below should work
                    //f.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    // this equates to equates to
                    //`PlacementFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
                    // Notify the fragment's listview it's data is changed.

                }
            }
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }
```

Again this could be optimised to only update the inner adapter when needed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  so do I need to put the mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); within the PlacementFragment or where should I put that?  Also in the getIemPosition method what adapter would I get with f.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  Thank you!

Comment: Added an update to show how I update the viewpager's pages (which is just before you view them). In `getItemPosition` you will get the `Fragment` being updated as an `Object`, you can then call any method's in the class the the Fragment is created from or access data variables that a visible. so `f.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ` equates to `PlacementFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I appreciate the help Andrew!  I made those changes and stepped through the code and object in getItemPosition is always PlacementFragment so the if(object instanceof PlacementListViewAdapter) is never triggered.

Comment: Sorry I must have copied and pasted the wrong Class name when adapting it from my classes to yours. It should be the type of the Fragment being drawn by the viewpager. I've updated the example.

Comment: I made those changes, the app runs, but the data is not changing.

Comment: Andrew can you take a look at the SearchActivity onPostEcecute method.  Once the data is back from the AsyncTask should I be updating the PageViewAdapter or the ListViewAdapter?  Then should I be calling a method to update or refresh the Activity or Fragment?

Comment: After another test I noticed the data in the ListView after the second page is updated but the first and second pages do not update.

Comment: There was a lot of commented out code in  SearchActivity and `onPostExecute` that did not make sense. And SearchActivity is not an "Activity" so it would be less confusing if it did not have Activity in the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204361/discussion-between-andrew-and-knlklabacka).